# How to process or excape variables inside of EOF to write file content?

Tags: shell, nginx, eof

This is how I create a file (`nginx.conf`) via shell.
As there are `$` characters in the filecontent I'm using `EOF`.

```
if [ $type == "nginx" ]; then
    cat > ${path}/nginx.conf <<'EOF'
server {
listen 3000;

location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;
}
EOF
fi
```

Now I have to use a dynamic port value, so instead of `listen 3000` I need to use `listen $port`.
But this won't work, as in the content there is also `$uri`, which should be handled as text, not as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only the delimiter itself, either all parameters are expanded or none.  You'll have to allow expansion, but escape the dollar signs for `$uri` to inhibit their expansion.

```
if [ "$type" = "nginx" ]; then
    cat > "${path}/nginx.conf" <<EOF
server {
listen $port;

location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.html = 404;
}

include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;
}
EOF
fi
```

The here document behaves like a double-quoted string:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo "$foo"
bar
$ echo "\$foo"
$foo
```

Comment: Should it be `listen $port` or `listen ${port}`?

Comment: Either is fine. `${port}` is the canonical way to write a parameter expansion, but the braces can be omitted since you aren't using any expansion operators and the `;` cannot be treated as part of the parameter name.

Comment: (Don't ask why I initially replaced the status code with `$port` instead of the port number. It's fixed now.)